# apply jquery function to multiple divs/elements with .click

Tags: jquery

hello very basic question

I have a number of divs (containing images) that I'd like to apply the same scaling function to (with a .click). But I'm not sure how to go about it. I think I need to use ".this" or ".target"?

Comment: Can you post the code you want to apply the jQuery to?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all the `div`s and then do:

```
$('.className').click(yourFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.className').die('click').live('click',function(){
//write your code here 
alert('clicked');
});
```

OR

```
$('.className').click(function(){

//write your code here 
alert('clicked');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.jQueryFunctionName = function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this));
}

jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("div, img").click(function () {
        console.log(jQuery(this)); // target element
        jQuery(this).jQueryFunctionName();
    });
});
```